# For a Toast with hyperlink how to have the url open on the same tab rather than a new tab

Tags: tab, hyperlink, toast

I have a function like the below to have a toast message with hyperlink. But the link is opening in a new tab. How to make the link open in the same tab or is there a way to set target=_self

```
const event = new ShowToastEvent({
    "title": "Success!",
    "message": "Record {0} created! See it {1}!",
    "messageData": [
        'Salesforce',
        {
            url: 'http://www.salesforce.com/',
            label: 'here'
        }
    ]
});
```